# Bluetooth died and Windows is not able to recover

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I have a pretty new Dell G5 5590 and 3 days ago its bluetooth adapter stopped working and I was not able to bring it back on. It has a Qualcomm QCA61x4A Wlan + Bluetooth board and only the bluetooth device is affected.

I have tried pretty much everything I know to fix this, reinstalling the drivers, rolling back driver version, forcing Windows to use an even older version and the *helpful* Windows troubleshooting tool, but anything worked so far.

I have been also trying to track and understand what happened to be able to at least search for anything new but the errors or clues I found wasn't sufficient.
So, I decided to post it here hoping someone can see something I'm not.
Here is a screenshot of the current state:

[image]

Let me know if any other information is necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming it's not under warranty (if it is, just back it up to an external drive or some cloud accounts and have it replaced), delete the Bluetooth entry in Device Manager (the whole Bluetooth entry, then close Device Manager, Then go to Start > Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices.  Select Add Bluetooth or other device and follow the instructions.

If it doesn't find the Bluetooth adapter, or it finds it but can't add it, the adapter is bad.  (You can buy a USB Bluetooth adapter at Amazon [if you're where hey ship to] for US$5-$15.  They work as well as the ones in the laptop do (when they're working).

Or ... you *could* order a new internal adapter from Dell (or any other supplier of Qualcom Bluetooth adapters) and replace it yourself, if you're good with opening laptops.  (There shouldn't be any soldering - there should be 2 wires that connect with slide-on clips.)  But a USB adapter is easy enough for anyone to add.

If you really want to see if Windows is the cause, run the repair partition, or the installation disk (or even download an image and burn a disk and boot with it - and repair.  (That reinstalls Windows, the drivers, etc., but doesn't touch your files or your registry.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually did that in-place windows install, but that did not work too. But I think you helped me to see something. I`ll try to find any registry issues related to this adapter and clear everything. From there I will try reinstall the drivers and check if it comes back to life. Thanks!